# Upgrade to Windows 10: speaker volume is not as high as it used to be

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-10-upgrade, dell-xps

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to 10 on my Dell XPS 13. It comes with the following audio devices and associated drivers:

[image]

I have version **6.0.1.7544** of the audio driver installed

[The audio drivers available for Windows 10 on the Dell website specific to my laptop can be found here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/BTJDVW1/drivers). At the time of writing, the driver version shown in the Dell site is **6.0.1.7509** which is weird because if I install the version shown by Dell, Windows 10 is happy to upgrade to the newer version.

However, no matter which of the above two versions I use, my sound volume is no where as high as it used to be before the upgrade.

Needless to say, I have checked all the obvious sound properties to no avail.

Looking to see if anyone has any suggestions as to what I can do.

Comment: Does win10 have the "sample rate" adjustment in sounds playback speaker properties advanced?  Where the final mix output sample and bit rates can be changed from "cd quality" to "Studio quality"   That can make variations in output levels depending on the audio device and whatever is happening. Plus any normalisation (loudness equalise) or enviroment effects applied in enhancements, Plus Level and Balance in both the speaker section and in levels. Plus the speaker configuration matching, plus any room correction.  so many buttons so little time :-)

Comment: Any of those features may have been un-noticably on and running without people particularly paying atttention to how they are set, just because it worked ok. A combination of 3 features can change the sound output levels up to like 4+ times, without the actual level adjustment having moved  Room correction  +-10db and equalisation +- many decibles, is not even shown in the windows properties, and may not even exist for some setups, it is only in the seperated software packages often.

Comment: Tried the above without any success...

Comment: I spent a few hours looking into that , and got nothing. summary of all that I saw. Manufacture supplied driver may have had tweaks that fit well into the supplied hardware, If they ever put one up for 10 grab it. . .  Changing (forcing install) to a legasy realtek ,or microsoft generic HD audio driver changes the level some, but of course updates knocks that out again. Many people tried many driver updates available, some with worse bugs, no one indicated yet that any one of them solved this issue.  I would submit a report to manufacture and MS so at least you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled both sound controllers shown, scanned for new hardware and accepted what was found. Volume increased back to what it had been previously. Worked for me, hopefully will work for you.

Comment: Just tried this. No luck.